# Controller and services are not loading in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-service

I have integrated requirejs with my angular app. 
But while loading app, it gives me an error `'Argument 'appCtrl' is not a function, got undefined'`

Here is my controller code :

```js
define(['Angular'], function (angular) {
   function appCtrl($scope, pathServices) {
     alert('sa');
   }

   function homeCtrl($scope, brandService) {
         console.log('dfd');
   }
});
```

And along with this, it gives error for `'unknown provider pathServices'`

Service code is :

### serviceConfig.js

```
define([
    'Angular',
    'common/Services/services',
    'current/js/services'
], function(angular, commonServices, loacalStorageServices, currentServices) {
    "use strict";

    var services = {
        commonServices : commonServices,
        currentServices : currentServices,
    };

    var initialize = function (angModule) {
        angular.forEach(services,function(service, name) {
            angModule.service(name, service);
        });
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

### common/services.js

```
define(['Angular'], function (angular) {
   var app = angular.module('myApp.services', []);
   app.factory('pathServices', function($http, $q, $rootScope) {
    function pathServices() {
            alert('as');
    }
    return new pathServices();
   });

   app.factory('anotherServices', function($http, $q, $rootScope) {
    function anotherServices() {
            alert('as');
    }
    return new anotherServices();
   });
});
```

### current/services.js

```
define(['Angular'], function(angular) {

    var app = angular.module('myApp.services', []);

    app.factory('brandsService', function() {
        function brandsService() {
            var autoCompleteData = [];
            this.getSource =  function() {
                return autoCompleteData;
            }

            this.setSource = function(states) {
                autoCompleteData = states;
            }
        }
        return new brandsService();
    });
});
```

in serviceConfig.js I have included 2 service files.. But the problem is, the last current/service.js file overwrites all files.. How can I include multiple service files ?

I am new to requirejs. How can I use controller function and services using requirejs ?
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your functions in the global (window) namespace, or register them in your module with the `moduleName.controller('controllerName',controllerFn)`

So either

```js
define(['Angular'], function (angular) {
 window.appCtrl = function($scope, pathServices) {
   alert('sa');
 }

 window.homeCtrl = function($scope, brandService) {
     console.log('dfd');
  }
});
```

or

```js
define(['Angular'], function (angular) {
 var module = angular.module('theModuleName');
 module.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, pathServices) {
   alert('sa');
 });

 module.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, brandService) {
     console.log('dfd');
  }
});
```

should fix this error (I prefer the second approach).

Comment: You have to make sure that the module is defined first, or define it in that function - then it'll work as well

Comment: controller functions are nw working fine but services are not still getting called.. Any idea ? how to import different services like i explained above in code using requirejs ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your code, how do you define your services? Does it work if you do the service definition in the same block as where you define your controllers?

Comment: If you can recreate your problem in a simple plunker it'd be easier to help

Comment: If you crate a plunker I'll have a look

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30740/discussion-between-joakimbl-and-amss)